# No Title Bar theme - The title bar is still appearing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

I want "no title bar" in my android app.

I have changed AndroidManifest.xml from AppTheme.NoActionBar to Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen .But the title bar is in grey color.
I've not got any style for Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen theme.

I also want to change navigation menu icon color. 
the menu icon is also not changing.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by:

> I want "no title bar" in my android app.

and then:

> I also want to change navigation menu icon color

Where is the menu icon supposed to show if not on the title bar?

Anyway, here is a backward compatible way to remove the title bar in your app:

- Extend `AppCompatActivity` in your activities
- Use `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` as the parent theme for your (app/activity) theme
- Inside this theme, set these flags

  ```
   <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
   <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
  ```
- Finally, apply the theme to your app or activities in `AndroidManifest.xml` with `android:theme="@style/your_no_title_bar_theme"`

Comment: thank you. what I meant was that I have got navigation drawer menu which appears on top of screen along with title bar. so I don't want title bar. I want navigation drawer menu icon to be in visible color. I have tried adding  parent ="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" in my theme which is Apptheme.MoActionBar but still not tilebar apprearing

Comment: @user1439582 Sorry, did you just say 'still no titlebar appearing'? isn't the whole question about you _not_ wanting a titlebar?
if I understand you correctly, you want **no titlebar** but still want a **drawer icon**, right?
I haven't played with that recently, but I think the icon is part of the titlebar, it goes away with it.
You can, however, still add an `ImageButton` and give it the same effects of a real drawer icon

Comment: are you saying there is no solution to implement Navigation drawer menu with out having title bar and titlebar is mandatory for Navigation drawer ?

Comment: I think the drawer is going to be there (will probably slide in if you swipe right) but I just don't get the visual design you are trying to achieve here.
Where would the drawer icon (sandwich) sit ? on the background? doesn't it look wrong? can you show me a simple illustration/image of the design on your mind?

Comment: The theme flags finally eliminated the blue title bar from appearing for me, after making an extensive search and consuming hours of time.

Answer (score 0):

here the following code : ( if i got your question right )

`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Window w = getWindow();
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        }`

Comment: what's your device/emulator API level ?

Answer (score 0):

Also look at the activity's theme

```
 <application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code for the full-screen application:

```
    //Remove title bar
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

//Remove notification bar
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

//set content view AFTER ABOVE sequence (to avoid crash)
this.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_name_here);
```

and also put below lines into style file:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

and into manifest apply this style to activity:

```
<activity
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
```

Comment: I've tried this solution but still titlebar appearing